# How to pass data from HTML form to Database in Django

Tags: python, html, django

Can you help me with this issue? I want to pass data from HTML form to Database.
This is my HTML form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}" disabled><br>
    <label for="image">Image: </label>
    <input id="image" type="file" name="image">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

And this is my Views.py

```
class CreateProfile(CreateView):
    template_name = 'layout/add_photo.html'
    model = Profile
    fields = ['image', 'user']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('git_project:index')
```

When I fill in the form (username is equal to logged in username, and chose an image) and when I click "Save Changes", the data has to be passed in Database in table Profile. Here is class Profile in models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField()
```

I know this is basic, but I don't know how to fix it up, so please, help! :)

Comment: And what errors do you have now? 

Basically you need to overwrite post on CreateProfile - and probably define a Form which allows you map the username to the right user (OneToOneField) - share more details ;)

Comment: That is what CreateView already does. What problem are you having?

Comment: When I click "Save Changes", nothing happens. I am not redirect to index page, it leaves me in this page, and there is no errors, and when I check my database, I haven't any changes, everything is the same. What kind of more details do you need? :) And thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I match fields in class CreateProfile with fields in HTML form, and if I can, how to do it? :)

Comment: I solved problem. In HTML form id='username' and name='username' must be the same like fields in class CreateProfile, id="user" name="user". Everything works perfect! Thanks one more time! :)